# How to use a .swc File in Flash CS6?

Tags: flash, flash-cs6, swc

I'm currently attempting to use the Citrus Engine http://citrusengine.com/

However, it gives me a .swc file and I've not used flash in a good while, so I updated it to the CS6 so I could develop a few side-scroller games with my friend. However, I've been unable to find anything relating to using the .swc file in the flash. I've tried the extension manager, opening it directly from the folder.

Extension manager doesn't show anything at all, opening it directly just gives me "Unexpected file format."

Thanks for the help.

Rion

Comment: try this: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/879050